# Jersey: How to log HTTP POST data?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I have a code block like

```
    final Invocation.Builder builder = webTarget.request();
    final Entity<IFSRequestPresentation> entity = Entity.entity(ifsRequestPresentation, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    final Response response = builder.post(entity);
```

The server (which is external to me and I can't see logs) is not returning me the data I expect. I believe that the `json` payload is not good

The `IFSRequestPresentation` is quite complex and I would like to see how it is represented as  `json` `String`.

I am using `Spring`**(4.0.3)** and `Jersey`**(2.8)**.

Is there a way I can log `builder.post(entity)` method? or at least see what `entity` looks like as `json` String?

Comment: Can't you access the site using curl and see the json in the body of the response?

Comment: I want to see how java object turns to `json`

Comment: Do you want to learn how this particular object turns into json or do you want to know in general how the transformation happens?

Comment: Did you try using `entity.toString()`?

Comment: You could try to extend the `MessageBodyWriter` that is provided by your json framework and log the serialized entity there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote it to file like

```
mapper.writeValue(new File("my.json"), IFSRequestPresentation);
```

as per Jackson [documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) and got the json written to that file